# Passing parsed JSON Data from data Model to View Controller

Tags: ios, swift3

Ok, I have been stuck on this for days. I have a AuthService class that authenticates and requests an account by Id, and then uses a static function in an Account Data class to parse the JSON data. I have a delegate in the AuthService class that I call in my viewController. Well I can see my data when its parsed when I call my delegate. I want to be able to use this parsed data in my viewController. I have been going around and around, I cannot figure out to access this data. Here is my relevant code...

// AuthService.swift

```
protocol AuthServiceDelegate: class {
    func loadMe()
 }

class AuthService {
  static let instance = AuthService()
  weak var delegate: AuthServiceDelegate?
  var account = Account()
  var myAccount = [Account]()

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var DEFAULTS_ID = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "DEFAULTS_ID")
var _id: String?

  func fetchProfile(for id: String) {
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    guard let URL = URL(string: "\(GET_ACCOUNT_ID)/\(account.id)") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let token = self.authToken
    request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application-json")

    do {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                // Success
                let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                print("URL Session Task for fetching Account By ID Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode) :Account info loaded" )
                // Parse JSON Data
                if let data = data {
                    self.myAccount = Account.parseAccountJSONData(data: data)
                    self.delegate?.loadMe()
                }
            } else {
                // Failure
                print("URL Session Task Failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()

    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}
```

// Account Data Model - Account.swift

```
class Account {

var id: String = ""
var username: String = ""
var name: String = ""
var bio: String = ""
var profileImageURL: String = ""
var website: String = ""
var __v: Int?

static func parseAccountJSONData(data: Data) -> [Account] {

    var myAccount = [Account]()

    do {

        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
        print(jsonResult)

        if let accountData = jsonResult as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] {
            for info in accountData {
                var accountInfo = Account()
                accountInfo.username = info["username"] as! String
                accountInfo.id = info["_id"] as! String
                accountInfo.name = info["name"] as! String
                accountInfo.bio = info["bio"] as! String
                accountInfo.profileImageURL = info["profileImageURL"] as! String
                accountInfo.website = info["website"] as! String
                accountInfo.__v = info["__v"] as! Int
                myAccount.append(accountInfo)

                print("This is your account USER_ID \(accountInfo.id)")

            } // else // { return }
        }
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
    return myAccount
}
```

// ViewController Class

```
class ProfileVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bioLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var websiteLabel: UILabel!

var authService = AuthService.instance
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var logInVC: LogInVC?
var DEFAULTS_ID = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "DEFAULTS_ID")
var currentAccount: Account!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    authService.delegate = self

    authService.fetchProfile(for: DEFAULTS_ID as! String)

    if let account = currentAccount {

        authService.fetchProfile(for: DEFAULTS_ID as! String)

        nameLabel.text = account.name
        bioLabel.text = account.bio
        websiteLabel.text = currentAccount.website
    }
    print(DEFAULTS_ID!)

}

extension ProfileVC: AuthServiceDelegate {
    func loadMe() {
    }
}
```

This is the route and for an authenticated user to findById 
[image]
Here is the data being called in my viewController from the delegate in my AuthService via the Account class.
[image]
 My question is how do I access this data to update my UI in my viewController? I have been stuck on this for days. The other dbCollections I have work because they are all loaded in TableViews with configured cells by their ObjectIds of their respective classes. Yet I can't get this to work when not using a tableview as I only want authenticated users to access their profile so they can update their info.

HELP.. I have gotten the data parsed several by several different routes and GETS, but I am at a loss to access this specific data unless I am using a collectionView or tableView, which I do not need.